# Android ImageView not displaying correctly

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

[image]Does any one else have this issue? Sometime when my images are downloaded from the api, I display them in an image view using : binding?.imgView?.setImageBitmap(it)

Some times when the image is displayed in the image view, half of it is cut off. how do I fix it? See image?

android:scaleType="fitXY", other scale types aren't valid for my app meaning this is the one I want to use. I know this is stretching the image but why doesn't the system display properly? is the common? should I reload the imageView? if so, what is the best way.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
           <com.appnaq.adventures.mystatis.views.generic.GenericImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if you are loading image from API, why can't you use image caching libraries like Glide, Picasso or coil? Which loads image efficiently, also you can transform your image as you like using those libraries.

Comment: Use Glid its best to load an image when u downlaod

Comment: will try glide, but why wouldn't it work otherwise? @GeneralTony

Comment: Can't say anything with this without seeing your layout code, If you could send them it would be helpful to debug.